# ¿$(document).on(event) no funciona?

Tags: jquery

Estoy añadiendo objetos dinámicamente, y me encuentro que `$(document).on('click', function(){//código});` no me funciona :/

también probé con:

```
$(".tr").off('click').on('click', function(){//código});
```

Comment: ¿Intentas añadir un `listener` soble los elementos `<tr>` o sobre los elementos con clase `<TAG class="tr"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tuve el mismo problema, hace tiempo
lo solucione con:
(nota 1: selecciono table como ejemplo, pero tu puedes cambiar a un padre de tu clase tr)

```
$("table").on('click','.tr', function(){alert();});
```

(nota 2: no te recomiendo usa $(document), ya que también tuve el mismo problema )
si tienes dudas checa este link:
[Eventos creados de forma dinámica](http://javiermiguelgarcia.blogspot.mx/2014/07/jquery-anadir-eventos-elementos-creados.html)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo real que te lleva recomendar este código por sobre el publicado por el autor?

Answer (score 0):

Deberias revisar tu version de jquery, si es la 3 ++ es probable que sea eso, o tambien podrias hacer que al momento de generar los elementos, la primera vez importe el script con esto tendras el archivo cargado al mismo tiempo que tus elementos.

Comment: En cuanto a la primera recomendación, sería recomendable consultarle al autor de la pregunta qué versión de jQuery está usando en un comentario (para tener en cuenta cuando tengas la suficiente reputación para comentar).... En cuanto a la segunda recomendación, no me queda del todo claro, ¿podrías agregar un fragmento de código como ejemplo?